# Why softmax is preserving pattern when applied along different axes in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I am calculating the softmax function over a matrix containing random float values using the following methods:

1. row-wise
2. column-wise
3. Considering the whole matrix

After calculating the values, I have drawn the heatmaps of each resulting matrix. As I have noticed, the patterns in the heatmap (the relative sizes of each cell) are the same for all three methods. I drew this for several random matrices and experienced the same.

What is the reason for this?

If you need to experiment, I have created a [Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-v7UQ9xGQrUMBDI1XsTwx1wD_K7_FHNT?usp=sharing) with Python code.

Comment: because softmax preserves order.

Comment: @whoisit I don't understand. When doing softmax row-wise vs. column-wise, the denominator changes row by row and column by column. How can order be preserved there?